# does vs2010 have an out of the box wizard creation control?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

is the creation of a wizard built into vs2010?
i am hoping they by now this boiler plate code is taken care of for developers by the IDE via a new server control.

if not then i hope there is a template or somethign out there for this mundane task of wizard creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the `asp.net` tag, so: there's a [Wizard server control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.aspx) that's been in the framework since version 2.0 (so Visual Studio 2005).